# How to get values from a nested array in javascript?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have an array like `let a = [[[1,2], [3,[1,2,3]]], [2,3]]` and want to access the elements using a method/way to return the values like : `12312323` or `[1,2,3,1,2,3,2,3]`

how can I approach the solution in javascript/nodeJS? 
thanks

Comment: [`Array.flat()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Objets_globaux/Array/flat)

Comment: [Try this link instead.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flat). Note, not available for Edge.

Answer (score -1):

You can use [`Array.flat()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flat)

```js
let a = [[[1,2], [3,[1,2,3]]], [2,3]]

let op = a.flat(Infinity)

console.log(op)
```

You can check browser compatibility here  [compatibility](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flat#Browser_compatibility)